Error message in Mvord: Multivariate ordered logit regression
I am stuck trying to perform a multivariate ordered logit regression using the mvord package in R. I would be eternally grateful if any of you could help me or point me in the right direction since I don't know how to proceed from here.
My independent variable is binary (threat_perception, where 0 = No threat perceived, 1 = threat perceived).
My dependent variables are different dimensions of liberal democracy, all ordinally scaled on either a 10-point Linkert scale or a 4-point Linkert scale.
All variables have been converted into ordered factors and rows containing missing values have been dropped from the dataset.
When trying to fit the model using mvord, a keep receiving this error message for every one of my 6 dependent variables: "1: For response 1, not all response levels are observed. Model might be non-identifiable"
This is my first attempt:
model_mvord_crime <- mvord(formula = MMO2(support_army_rule,
                                          support_expert_rule,
                                          support_checks_balances, 
                                          support_civil_rights,
                                          support_elections,
                                          support_equality) ~ 0 + immig_crime,
                           data = df_M1_2017,
                           link = mvprobit()))

This is the error message:
Error in check_response_missings(rho) : 
  Model is not identifiable. For at least one dimension, not all response categories are observed.
              Either remove the non-observed category or set constraints on the threshold parameters to ensure identifiability.
In addition: Warning messages:
1: For response 1, not all response
          levels are observed. Model might be non-identifiable if
          the thresholds for this response are not restricted. 
2: For response 2, not all response
          levels are observed. Model might be non-identifiable if
          the thresholds for this response are not restricted. 
3: For response 3, not all response
          levels are observed. Model might be non-identifiable if
          the thresholds for this response are not restricted. 
4: For response 4, not all response
          levels are observed. Model might be non-identifiable if
          the thresholds for this response are not restricted. 
5: For response 5, not all response
          levels are observed. Model might be non-identifiable if
          the thresholds for this response are not restricted. 
6: For response 6, not all response
          levels are observed. Model might be non-identifiable if
          the thresholds for this response are not restricted. 
> 

Reading up on the mvord package, I have tried constraining the thresholds so that all thresholds of the with a 4-point linkert scale and those with a 10-point linkert scale are set equally, respectively.
However, nothing seems to fix the mistake. Is there a limit to the number of levels that mvord can compute for ordinal data? Can anybody point out my mistake in trying to constrain the thresholds?
Thank you very much for your time and effort, I really appreciate it.
This is my second attempt: I have attempted to create threshold constraints first for the group of variables that share the 4-point linkert scale.
library(mvord)

check_args_thresholds <- function(rho) {
  # CHECK if threshold.values is in line with threshold.constraints
  if (length(rho$threshold.constraints) != rho$ndim) {
    stop("Dimensions of threshold.values and number of outcomes do not match", call. = FALSE)
  }
  if (any(sapply(seq_len(rho$ndim), function(j) length(rho$threshold.values[[j]]) != rho$ntheta[j]))) {
    stop("Dimensions of threshold.values and number of thresholds do not match", call. = FALSE)
  }
  for (j in unique(rho$threshold.constraints)) {
    ind <- which(rho$threshold.constraints == j)
    if (length(unique(rho$threshold.values[ind])) != 1) {
      stop("If constraints are set on thresholds (by threshold.constraints), threshold.values need to be specified accordingly for these outcome dimensions. Maybe dimensions do not have the same number of threshold parameters.", call. = FALSE)
    }
  }
}


rho <- list(
  ndim = 3,  # Number of dimensions (response variables)
  ntheta = c(3, 3, 3),  # Number of thresholds for each dimension
  threshold.constraints = c(1, 1, 1),  # Constraints for each dimension
  threshold.values = list(
    support_army_rule = c(1, 2, 3),
    support_expert_rule = c(1, 2, 3),
    support_checks_balances = c(1, 2, 3)
  )
)


# Run the check function
check_args_thresholds(rho)


# Correct the spelling of threshold.constraints
threshold_constraints <- list(
  support_army_rule = c(1, 1, 1,1),
  support_expert_rule = c(1, 1, 1,1),
  support_checks_balances = c(1, 1, 1,1)
)

# Fit the model using mvord with the specified threshold constraints
model_mvord_crime <- mvord(
  formula = MMO2(support_army_rule,
                 support_expert_rule,
                 support_checks_balances) ~ 0 + immig_crime,
  data = df_M1_2017,
  link = mvprobit(),
  threshold.constraints = threshold_constraints
)

